# QGIS TimeManager returning zero records

Tags: qgis, time, datetime, timemanager, temporal-controller

I am using QGIS 3.26 and TimeManager 3.6 and have imported a GPX file with ~10000 times in a qDateTime field called "time". Viewing the label and attribute table show these appear to be correct. I am using an international date format and the date is showing as 18/07/2020 19:19:03 and the data runs for about three hours to 22:19:00. I am using accumulate

The filter that TimeManager is creating is
`cast("time" as character) < '2020-07-18T19:47:19' AND cast("time" as character) >= '0001-01-01T00:00:00'` and this should have about 1000 records returned however returns zero however if you set the year to 2021 or 2022, it returns all ~10k of records.
If you use the query `"time"  < '2020-07-18T19:47:19'` (without the cast),this brings back the correct number of 1000 records.

Has anyone seen this issue (not with TimeManager) but the cast function please?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for testing? You mean TimeManager (= plugin) or Temporal Controller (= core feature)? If using the plugin, have a look at Temporal Controller. Sometimes, datetime values in the attribute table are saved in another time zone then your local machine - that is often a cause of problems, so check this

Comment: Thanks @Babel - I did mean the TimeManager plugin and the timezone looks like it was out by about 11 hours so assume this was the case. I swapped to the Temporal Controller and it worked a treat straight away.

Answer (score 1):

As @babel mentioned, this maybe a timezone disconnect with the plugin TimeManager as the timed range was only three hours but the timezone was 11 hours earlier than UTC. A longer period may have returned some of the data and pointed to the issue.

I reverted to Temporal Controller and it worked correctly first time.

Comment: Glad it worked! Just to be clear: I encountered a mismatch between diffent time zones in Temporal Controller as well. So be sure to check this next time when you have problems.